# I'm trying to return some data from http request in angular js but it gives an undefined

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

**Here is the controller of angular js that is calling the service to get the hotels**

```
   vm.getTopHotels =  function(){
         var hotelsLimit =  10;
         var top_hotels = 
         dataService.getHotels()
          .then(function(hotels){
             console.log('adf');
              sortHotels = commonMethods.sortHotels(hotels.data.data,'Rating','SORT_DESC'); 
              hotelDetailsCheck = checkDetailsIfExists(sortHotels);
              //Get only top 10 hotels for home page
              top_hotels =  hotelDetailsCheck.slice(0,10);
              vm.topHotels =  top_hotels;
          },
          function(data){
              console.log('Failed to get Hotels');
          }); 
     };

     vm.getTopHotels();
```

** And here is the dataService that is calling the Http get request to get the data but in the controller, it gives me undefined so is there something wrong in the datsService return method because I think it is not returning **

```
(function(){  
    angular
       .module('app')
       .factory('dataService',DataFactory);

       DataFactory.$inject = ['$http','$q']

       function DataFactory($http,$q){
          var service = {
              hotels:[],
              getHotels:getHotels,
              saveHotels:saveHotels
          };
           return service;

          function saveHotels(){
            var def = $q.defer();
             $http.get('/hotels/saveHotelsData')
              .then(function successCallback(data){
                    def.resolve(data);
               },function errorCallback(data){
                  def.reject('Something went down :(');
               });
               return def.promise;
          }

         function getHotels(){
            // var def = $q.defer();

           return  $http.get('/hotels/getHotelsData')
               .then(function successCallback(data){
                   service.hotels = data;
                });


          }


       }

})();
```

Comment: add dataservice code, its missing

Comment: ok I have added can you let me know the problem thanks

Comment: is this right to use this type of return ?

  return  $http.get('/hotels/getHotelsData')
               .then(function successCallback(data){
                   service.hotels = data;
                });

Comment: you have to `return data;` as answer suggests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ...
.then(function(data) {
    console.log('adf');
    sortHotels = commonMethods.sortHotels(hotels.data.data,'Rating','SORT_DESC');
```

What's `hotels`? It isn't declared anywhere. If `hotels` is supposed to be the response from API, then it should be declared so:

```
.then(function(hotels) {
    console.log('adf');
    sortHotels = commonMethods.sortHotels(hotels.data.data,'Rating','SORT_DESC');
```

Update: your `getHotels` passes results through a function without return statement, hence will resolve to undefined. Should be

```
         function getHotels(){
           return  $http.get('/hotels/getHotelsData')
               .then(function successCallback(data) {
                   service.hotels = data;
                   return data;
                });
          }
```

Comment: that is not hotels that is data instead of hotels that was mistaken 
but the error is same that data is not defined it is not returnig from dataService

Comment: Then the problem might be in dataService

Comment: can you look at the dataSservice code and let me know the problem if you see any ?

Comment: Just a note that AngularJS Factories are singletons, setting service.hotels to the response will cause all instances of DataFactory to have that shared variable. I would not recommend doing this.